# How do I set a random image from an array invisible when a button is pressed

Tags: android-studio

I am building an app that when a button is pressed a random image in a gridLayout disappears revealing something behind it.

There are 28 images in the gridLayout.

I have my images in an array and inside the buttons onClick i want to get a random image from that array and set its visibility to invisible.

I appreciate if anyone can help.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    

    ImageView image1;

    ImageView image2;

    ImageView image3;

    ImageView image4;

    ImageView image5;

    ImageView image6;

    ImageView image7;

    ImageView image8;

    ImageView image9;

    ImageView image10;

    ImageView image11;

    ImageView image12;

    ImageView image13;

    ImageView image14;

    ImageView image15;

    ImageView image16;

    ImageView image17;

    ImageView image18;

    ImageView image19;

    ImageView image20;

    ImageView image21;

    ImageView image22;

    ImageView image23;

    ImageView image24;

    ImageView image25;

    ImageView image26;

    ImageView image27;

    ImageView image28;

    Button revealButton;

    Random rand;


    Integer[] imagesArray = {

            R.id.imageView1,
            R.id.imageView1,
            R.id.imageView2,
            R.id.imageView3,
            R.id.imageView4,
            R.id.imageView5,
            R.id.imageView6,
            R.id.imageView7,
            R.id.imageView8,
            R.id.imageView9,
            R.id.imageView10,
            R.id.imageView11,
            R.id.imageView12,
            R.id.imageView13,
            R.id.imageView14,
            R.id.imageView15,
            R.id.imageView16,
            R.id.imageView17,
            R.id.imageView18,
            R.id.imageView19,
            R.id.imageView20,
            R.id.imageView21,
            R.id.imageView22,
            R.id.imageView23,
            R.id.imageView24,
            R.id.imageView25,
            R.id.imageView26,
            R.id.imageView27,
            R.id.imageView28


    };

    public void reveal(View view) {

    }





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        

        image1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        image3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        image4 = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        image5 = findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        image6 = findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        image7 = findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        image8 = findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        image9 = findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        image10 = findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        image11 = findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
        image12 = findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
        image13 = findViewById(R.id.imageView13);
        image14 = findViewById(R.id.imageView14);
        image15 = findViewById(R.id.imageView15);
        image16 = findViewById(R.id.imageView16);
        image17 = findViewById(R.id.imageView17);
        image18 = findViewById(R.id.imageView18);
        image19 = findViewById(R.id.imageView19);
        image20 = findViewById(R.id.imageView20);
        image21 = findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
        image22 = findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
        image23 = findViewById(R.id.imageView23);
        image24 = findViewById(R.id.imageView24);
        image25 = findViewById(R.id.imageView25);
        image26 = findViewById(R.id.imageView26);
        image27 = findViewById(R.id.imageView27);
        image28 = findViewById(R.id.imageView28);

        revealButton = findViewById(R.id.reveal);
        
        rand = new Random();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nextInt method like the code below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




Button revealButton;

Random rand;


Integer[] imagesArray = {

        R.id.imageView1,
        R.id.imageView1,
        R.id.imageView2,
        R.id.imageView3,
        R.id.imageView4,
        R.id.imageView5,
        R.id.imageView6,
        R.id.imageView7,
        R.id.imageView8,
        R.id.imageView9,
        R.id.imageView10,
        R.id.imageView11,
        R.id.imageView12,
        R.id.imageView13,
        R.id.imageView14,
        R.id.imageView15,
        R.id.imageView16,
        R.id.imageView17,
        R.id.imageView18,
        R.id.imageView19,
        R.id.imageView20,
        R.id.imageView21,
        R.id.imageView22,
        R.id.imageView23,
        R.id.imageView24,
        R.id.imageView25,
        R.id.imageView26,
        R.id.imageView27,
        R.id.imageView28


};

public void reveal(View view) {

int randomImagePosition= new Random().nextInt(imagesArray.length);
int imageId = imagesArray[randomImagePosition] ;
findViewById(imageId).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

}





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    

   

    revealButton = findViewById(R.id.reveal);
    




}
```

}

Comment: thank you, now where will I set the visibility of the images?

Comment: i modified my answer , check it out

Comment: this really helped thx